# PlatformIO:[upload] Error 2 with esp8266 ESP-07 board

Tags: platformio

I use `VSCODE` to create project. I create a project and select `ESp-07 board` and `ESP8266 RTOS SDK framework` then create a `main.c` file in `src` directory and copy content of `main.c` file of [`esp8266-rtos-sdk-blink`](https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif8266/blob/master/examples/esp8266-rtos-sdk-blink/src/main.c) example to my project `main.c` file. it `compile successfully` but when i want to upload it to my board following error occur :

> Processing esp07 (platform: espressif8266; framework: esp8266-rtos-sdk; board: esp07)
>   Verbose mode can be enabled via -v, --verbose option
>   CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif8266/esp07.html
>   PLATFORM: Espressif 8266 2.3.2 > Espressif Generic ESP8266 ESP-07
>   HARDWARE: ESP8266 80MHz, 80KB RAM, 4MB Flash
>   PACKAGES: toolchain-xtensa 1.40802.0 (4.8.2), framework-esp8266-rtos-sdk 1.5.0-beta.5, tool-esptool
>   1.413.0 (4.13), tool-esptoolpy 1.20800.0 (2.8.0), tool-mkspiffs 1.200.0 (2.0)
>   LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> bit.ly/configure-pio-ldf
>   LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
>   Found 0 compatible libraries
>   Scanning dependencies…
>   No dependencies
>   Building in release mode
>   Retrieving maximum program size .pio\build\esp07\firmware.elf
>   Checking size .pio\build\esp07\firmware.elf
>   Advanced Memory Usage is available via “PlatformIO Home > Project Inspect”
>   DATA: [==== ] 36.3% (used 29754 bytes from 81920 bytes)
>   PROGRAM: [======= ] 73.9% (used 278664 bytes from 376832 bytes)
>   Configuring upload protocol…
>   AVAILABLE: espota, esptool
>   CURRENT: upload_protocol = esptool
>   Looking for upload port…
>   Auto-detected: COM3
>   Uploading .pio\build\esp07\firmware.bin
>   esptool.py v2.8
>   Serial port COM3
>   Connecting…
>   Chip is ESP8266EX
>   Features: WiFi
>   Crystal is 26MHz
>   MAC: 5c:cf:7f:33:a6:e6
>   Uploading stub…
>   Running stub…
>   Stub running…
>   Configuring flash size…
>   Auto-detected Flash size: 1MB
>   A fatal error occurred: File C:\Users\MrTavakoli.platformio\packages\framework-esp8266-rtos-sdk\bin\esp_init_data_default.bin (length 128) at offset 4177920 will not fit in 1048576 bytes of flash. Use --flash-size argument, or change flashing address.
>   *** [upload] Error 2

I test my board with Arduino framework successfully.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use esp01-1M board instead of esp07 board and compile then upload to esp07 board successfully.
again change board to esp07 and add

> board_upload.maximum_size = 1048576

to platformio.ini file and compile and upload toesp07` board successfully.
I found 1048576 value from esp01_1m.json file.